# Use Delphi TMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting minimizing remoteapp after more than 10 seconds, the session will automatically disconnect

Tags: delphi, pascal, rdp, remoteapp

Use Delphi TMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting minimizing remoteapp after more than 10 seconds, the session will automatically disconnect

Environment: Client: Windows 10
Server: winserver 2008 R2

```
var
rdp: TMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting;
begin
rdp.AdvancedSettings9.RDPPort := 3389;
rdp.ControlInterface.UserName := 'username';
rdp.AdvancedSettings9.ClearTextPassword := 'password';
rdp.SecuredSettings2.KeyboardHookMode := 1;
rdp.DesktopWidth := Screen.Width;
rdp.DesktopHeight := Screen.Height;
rdp.RemoteProgram.RemoteProgramMode := True; //Enable the remoteapp mode
rdp.Connect;
end

//Connected Event start StartProgram
procedure rdpConnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
rdp.RemoteProgram.ServerStartProgram('D:\project1.exe','','D:\',False,'',False);
end;
```

Symptom: After minimizing (click the Minimize button or click the taskbar icon), the remote session is automatically disconnected more than 10 seconds after minimizing the program.
I tried setting the session time limit to “never on ” the group policy on the server, which didn't solve the problem.
The following related Settings are set.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753112(v=ws.10)?red irectedfrom=MSDN

and the client regedit has set RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized
Minimization will still break.

If anyone has the same problem as me?

client set regedit

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client]
"RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized"=dword:2

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client]
"RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized"=dword:2


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client]
"RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized"=dword:2


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client]
"RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized"=dword:2


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client]
"RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized"=dword:2


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services]
"MaxIdleTime"=dword:00000000
"KeepAliveEnable"=dword:00000001
"KeepAliveInterval"=dword:00002710
"fResetBroken"=dword:00000000
```

Using sendkeys regularly after minimization also won't keep the connection